# How to get ListView position and corresponding SimpleAdapter data of the row where checkbox was clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have a `ListView` which shows users names.The `ListView` get this data from the `SimpleAdapter`.Each row in this `ListView` has a `TextView` which shows users names and a `ComboBox` which is used for selecting corresponding name.The problem I don't know how to get row position and corresponding `SimpleAdapter` data of the currently checked `CheckBox`.How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you use `list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the index of the view which contains a checked checkbox.

Try this to get the index:

```
int index = listView.indexOfChild(checkBox.getParent());
```

Once you have the index, you can do this to get the  data:

```
View customView = listView.getChildAt(index);
```